# Loop through jQuery Mobile list view data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to loop through the data attribute of a jQuery Mobile listview, but I can only get the last element, and I really don't know why.

```
 var listItems = $("li.placesList");
listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    var $this = $(li);
    console.log($this.attr("id")); // It works as expected. It shows all ids
    console.log($this.data('distancia')); //It only shows the last item's data value  of the list

});
```

The way I'm assigning the data value in another part of the code is:

```
 $('<li class="placesList"></li>').data({
    location: pointsArray[pointCount].Location,
    distancia: distancia
});
```

I know this data is being added correctly.

In the console I see

Correct Values:

```
0.409 
0.26
```

Using the $each() loop, I see the three correct IDs, but only the data of the last element:

```
a //ID
0.26 
b //ID
0.26
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the whole assignment? I think the problem is there. Something like distancia[pointCount] or probably .each() is needed.

Comment: The correct values I obtained looping through pointsArray and the list at the same time in a different part of the code, but I don't get it to work just looping the list by itself. I'll try to show more code when I return to my computer. Thanks for looking into this.